# 1 Database for multiple WordPress themes

Tags: themes, database

I am the owner of a small company that makes wordpress websites for entrepeneurs. When we go to a customer, we want to show some examples of themes we could be going to use. We want the themes to display some information of the customer, like a logo. a header title and some personal information. We will probably be adding this information through the Customizer of the theme(s).

This will result in 3 different themes with identical information.

We can make 3 different databases and change `the wp-config.php` file to the right database name when we want to show a different theme, but we were wondering if there was another solution?

We only have 1 domain available, so it's not possible to put each theme on a different domain..

Comment: Why won't just switching theme in admin work? Also domain limitation sounds strange, even if you only _own_ one domain, spinning up subdomains is pretty typical, especially if you need it for work (and in theme dev you kind of do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to be visiting clients to show them your templates I would personally recommend installing Wordpress on your local computer by following the instructions on the below page.

https://managewp.com/how-to-create-a-local-wordpress-website-in-windows-with-xampp

Once you have installed Wordpress locally you could make a backup of your live Wordpress site and restore it on your local computer by following this guide.

https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Backups

Doing it this way you're not limited by your hosting providers 1 site only policy. You can also make modification without it affecting your live website in any way. You'll also avoid the embarrasing moment of not knowing whether it's a clients internet connection that's slow or the server the website sits on.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at "theme switching" plugins – there are a few free and premium plugins that let you switch the theme from front end.

One free theme switcher plugin that seems to be updated regularly is [MDC Theme Switcher](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mdc-theme-switcher/):

*"Upon activation, it adds a sricky bar to front-end with a dropdown list of availabe themes. Admin can select which of the installed themes should be available in this list."*

Comment: Ugh, was curious to check that plugin out (I developed similar one) and their implementation to just switch theme by arbitrary input without any security checks whatsoever seems waaay dangerous.

Comment: oh good to know! Thank you for leaving a note about this…